# How to find the limit of a Sequence $ f(n) = \frac{16f(n-1)-2}{32} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have this sequence:
\begin{equation}
f(n) = \frac{16f(n-1)-2}{32}
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
f(0) = 1
\end{equation}
I want to find it's limit while n goes to infinity and therefore check whether it converges or diverges. Could someone help me? I don't know what i can do here. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: In other words, $f(n)=\frac12f(n-1)-\frac1{16}$?

Comment: Hint: if the sequence converges, the limit will fulfill $f=(16f-2)/32$. If you find $f$, you should be able to use the $\delta/\epsilon$ rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $f(n) = \frac 1 2 f(n-1) - \frac 1 {16}$. In order to show that the limit must exist, let us use the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Convergence_of_a_monotone_sequence_of_real_numbers): if a sequence is decreasing and has a lower bound, then it is convergent.

Note that $f(0) \ge - \frac 1 8$. Assume that $f(n-1) \ge - \frac 1 8$; then, by induction, $f(n) = \frac 1 2 f(n-1) - \frac 1 {16} \ge \frac 1 2 (- \frac 1 8) - \frac 1 {16} = - \frac 1 8$, so $f(n) \ge - \frac 1 8 \, \forall n$, so $f$ is bounded below.

Now $f(n) - f(n-1) = -\frac 1 2 f(n-1) - \frac 1 {16} = - \frac 1 2 (f(n-1) + \frac 1 8) \le 0$ (because all the terms are greater than $- \frac 1 8$, so $f$ is decreasing.

Being lower-bounded and decreasing, $f$ must have a limit, call it $l$. Passing to the limit in the recurrence relationship gives $l = \frac l 2 - \frac 1 {16}$, so $l = - \frac 1 8$.

Comment: Why did you choose -1 / 8 at first ? You said that f(0) >= -1/8 How did you came up with that number? Could we also use another number to prove this?

Comment: @RestlessC0bra: Good question. Initially I had chosen to show that $f(n) \ge -1$ (along the same line of thought). Then I realized that this wouldn't help me prove monotonicity. I then tried to slowly increase this lower bound up to something more useful. Also, these problems are solved by cheating: first you  compute the limit, and only next do you show that it really exists. Therefore, I already knew that the limit was $-\frac 1 8$, so it came quite naturally to use it as a lower bound. Educated guesses are a very important approach in mathematics, don't underestimate them!

Answer (score 4):

Notice that $f(n)=\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{16}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2^i}\rightarrow -1/8.$

Comment: @user251257: thanks for catching that!

Comment: Thanks for answering. Why 1 / 2^n ?

Answer (score 2):

If the limit $f_n \to f$ exists, then it should fulfill
$$
\frac{16 f -2}{32} = f \Longrightarrow f = -\frac18.
$$ 
Now, notice that
$$
f(n) = \frac12 f(n-1) - \frac{1}{16} \leq f(n-1) \Longleftrightarrow f(n-1) \geq -\frac{1}{8}.
$$
Thus, the sequence becomes monotone non increasing if it remains greater than $-1/8$.

By induction, we prove that $f(n)\geq -1/8$:
$$
f(0)\geq -\frac18 \to OK
$$
$$f(n) = \frac12 f(n-1) - \frac{1}{16} \geq \frac12 \left(-\frac{1}{8}\right) - \frac{1}{16} = -\frac18, \quad \forall n \geq 1.
$$
Finally, we proved that the sequence is non decreasing, thus the limit exists and it is $f = -1/8$.

Comment: Sorry.. just saw the @Alex M.'s answer...!

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on Alex R.'s observation: You can determine that closed form by determining the sequence's generating function. Suppose $F(x)=\sum\limits_{n\ge0}f(n)x^n$.
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\ge1}f(n)x^n&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\ge1}f(n-1)x^n+\frac{1}{16}\sum_{n\ge1}x^n\\[1ex]
\sum_{n\ge0}f(n)x^n-f(0)&=\frac{1}{2}x\sum_{n\ge1}f(n-1)x^{n-1}+\frac{1}{16}\frac{1}{1-x}\\[1ex]
F(x)-1&=\frac{1}{2}x\sum_{n\ge0}f(n)x^n+\frac{1}{16}\frac{1}{1-x}\\[1ex]
F(x)-1&=\frac{1}{2}xF(x)+\frac{1}{16}\frac{1}{1-x}\\[1ex]
F(x)&=\frac{16-17x}{8(2-x)(1-x)}\\[1ex]
F(x)&=\frac{9}{4}\frac{1}{2-x}-\frac{1}{8}\frac{1}{1-x}\\[1ex]
F(x)&=\sum_{n\ge0}\underbrace{\left(\frac{9}{8}\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{8}\right)}_{f(n)}x^n
\end{align*}$$